# Conditional per TargetFramework in MsBuild 15

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

With the new MsBuild version it's really easy to target multiple frameworks and framework versions in .csproj project:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net40;net45;net461;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Now, how do I get a constant defined for each of them so that I can have certain code only be part of e.g. `netcoreapp1.1` pass and not full framework compilation?

I'd like to be able to add a preprocessor directive like this one:

```
#if NET_CORE
    // some code
#endif
```

And the same for full .NET Framework and possibly .NET Standard.

The other questions I found don't take new `<TargetFrameworks>` way of defining the framework into accounts. Stuff like this doesn't work:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == '.NETCoreApp' ">NET_CORE</DefineConstants>
```

Comment: Do the symbols [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries) work for you?

Comment: Hmm, there is none for .NET Core, but I can handle that by `#if NET40 || NET45 || NET461` and `#else`. Thanks @DavidG! You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: For info, they have added symbols for .Net Core now, see my updated answer :)

Comment: Any solution to getting the current version through `$(TargetFramework)` in MSBuild script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are already various preprocessor symbols defined that you can use. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries):

### .NET Framework

| Framework/Version | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| .NET Framework (any version) | `NETFRAMEWORK` |
| .NET Framework 2.0 | `NET20` |
| .NET Framework 3.5 | `NET35` |
| .NET Framework 4.0 | `NET40` |
| .NET Framework 4.5 | `NET45` |
| .NET Framework 4.5.1 | `NET451` |
| .NET Framework 4.5.2 | `NET452` |
| .NET Framework 4.6 | `NET46` |
| .NET Framework 4.6.1 | `NET461` |
| .NET Framework 4.6.2 | `NET462` |
| .NET Framework 4.7 | `NET47` |
| .NET Framework 4.7.1 | `NET471` |
| .NET Framework 4.7.2 | `NET472` |
| .NET Framework 4.8 | `NET48` |

### .NET Standard

| Framework/Version | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| .NET Standard (any version) | `NETSTANDARD` |
| .NET Standard 1.0 | `NETSTANDARD1_0` |
| .NET Standard 1.1 | `NETSTANDARD1_1` |
| .NET Standard 1.2 | `NETSTANDARD1_2` |
| .NET Standard 1.3 | `NETSTANDARD1_3` |
| .NET Standard 1.4 | `NETSTANDARD1_4` |
| .NET Standard 1.5 | `NETSTANDARD1_5` |
| .NET Standard 1.6 | `NETSTANDARD1_6` |
| .NET Standard 2.0 | `NETSTANDARD2_0` |
| .NET Standard 2.1 | `NETSTANDARD2_1` |

### .NET Core

| Framework/Version | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| .NET [Core] (any version) | `NETCOREAPP` |
| .NET Core 1.0 | `NETCOREAPP1_0` |
| .NET Core 1.1 | `NETCOREAPP1_1` |
| .NET Core 2.0 | `NETCOREAPP2_0` |
| .NET Core 2.1 | `NETCOREAPP2_1` |
| .NET Core 2.2 | `NETCOREAPP2_2` |
| .NET Core 3.0 | `NETCOREAPP3_0` |
| .NET Core 3.1 | `NETCOREAPP3_1` |

### .NET 5+

| Framework/Version | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| .NET 5.0 | `NET5_0` |
| .NET 6.0 | `NET6_0` |
| .NET 7.0 | `NET7_0` |

### Additional `<framework>_OR_GREATER` Symbols

From the release of .NET6, a suite of `<framework>_OR_GREATER` symbols were added:

For example:

| Target Framework | Symbols |
| --- | --- |
| .NET Framework | `NET48_OR_GREATER`, `NET472_OR_GREATER`, `NET471_OR_GREATER`, `NET47_OR_GREATER`, `NET462_OR_GREATER`, `NET461_OR_GREATER`, `NET46_OR_GREATER`, `NET452_OR_GREATER`, `NET451_OR_GREATER`, `NET45_OR_GREATER`, `NET40_OR_GREATER`, `NET35_OR_GREATER`, `NET20_OR_GREATER` |
| .NET Standard | `NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD2_0_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_6_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_5_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_4_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_3_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_2_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_1_OR_GREATER`, `NETSTANDARD1_0_OR_GREATER` |
| .NET 5+ (and .NET Core) | `NET7_0_OR_GREATER`,`NET6_0_OR_GREATER`, `NET5_0_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER`, `NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER` |
| .NET 5+ (and .NET Core), OS Specific | `NET6_0_ANDROID_OR_GREATER`, `NET6_0_IOS_OR_GREATER`, `NET6_0_MACOS_OR_GREATER`, `NET6_0_MACCATALYST_OR_GREATER`, `NET6_0_TVOS_OR_GREATER`, `NET6_0_WINDOWS_OR_GREATER` |

```cs
#if NETSTANDARD1_6
    Console.WriteLine("This is .Net Standard 1.6");
#endif

#if NETCOREAPP2_0
    Console.WriteLine("This is .Net Core 2.0");
#endif
```

Comment: There are also `NETFRAMEWORK`, `NETSTANDARD` and `NETCOREAPP` symbols if you don't care about the exact version.

Comment: @JakubJanuszkiewicz They were added with .NET Core 3.x I believe, finally got round to adding them (and .NET 5!) in, thanks.

Comment: Why might these symbols not be defined in a C# project? `#if DEBUG` and `#if !DEBUG` both work, but none in the list above appear to be defined. Project properies show that `Target framework` is set to `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
[image]

This is the reference for how to write the code for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: These are instructions on how to target frameworks, not what the op asked for.