# Setting for formatting C-style comments for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Writing C# in Visual Studio 2019. With the following construct:

```
/* My comment
*/
```

Set the cursor to the right of `comment` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This gets converted to:

```
/* My comment
 *
*/
```

I'd prefer:

```
/* My comment

*/
```

After hunting around in `Tools > Options`, could not find the setting for this...where is it?

Comment: If the VS Text Editor options for code formatting isn't enough, you can take a look at https://www.atomineerutils.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Visual Studio options and navigate to:

*Text Editor* ► *C#* ► *Advanced*

and uncheck *Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /* */ comments*

[image]

Comment: @Sinatr I know, but it meant doing a fancy screengrab instead of a single keypress. But if it makes you happier... :)

Comment: Now is beautiful!

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks! Today is a good day, because now we can do [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42754213/1663001)!

Comment: Tables are awesome!