# Is it possible to use #if NET6_0_OR_GREATER to exclude a benchmark method from a BenchmarkDotNet run?

Tags: c#, multitargeting, benchmarkdotnet

Suppose that you're writing some benchmarks for use with BenchmarkDotNet that are multi-targeted to `net48` and `net6.0`, and that one of those benchmarks can only be compiled for the `net6.0` target.

The obvious thing to do is to use something like this to exclude that particular benchmark from the `net48` build:

```
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER

[Benchmark]
public void UsingSpan()
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    writeUsingSpan(stream, _array);
}

static void writeUsingSpan(Stream output, double[] array)
{
    var span  = array.AsSpan();
    var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(span);

    output.Write(bytes);
}

#endif // NET6_0_OR_GREATER
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, and the way in which it doesn't work depends on the order of the targets specified in the `TargetFrameworks` property in the project file.

If you order the frameworks so that `net6.0` is first as `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>` then (in the example above) the `UsingSpan()` method is included in BOTH targets, resulting in BenchmarkDotNet build errors for the `net48` target and output such as this:

```
|            Method |                Job |            Runtime |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|------------------ |------------------- |------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
| UsingBitConverter |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 325.587 us | 2.0160 us | 1.8858 us |
|      UsingMarshal |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 505.784 us | 4.3719 us | 4.0894 us |
|         UsingSpan |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 |   4.942 us | 0.0543 us | 0.0482 us |
| UsingBitConverter | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 |         NA |        NA |        NA |
|      UsingMarshal | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 |         NA |        NA |        NA |
|         UsingSpan | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 |         NA |        NA |        NA |
```

On the other hand, if you If order the frameworks so that `net48` is first as `<TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>` then (in the example above) the `UsingSpan()` method is *excluded* for both targets, resulting output such as this:

```
|            Method |                Job |            Runtime |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------------------ |------------------- |------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
| UsingBitConverter |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 343.1 us |  6.51 us | 11.57 us |
|      UsingMarshal |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 539.5 us | 10.77 us | 22.94 us |
| UsingBitConverter | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 | 331.2 us |  5.43 us |  5.08 us |
|      UsingMarshal | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 | 588.9 us | 11.18 us | 10.98 us |
```

I have to solve this issue by single-targeting the project and editing the project file to target the frameworks separately, and then run the benchmarks separately for each target.

Is there a way to make this work with a multi-targeted project?

---

For completeness, here's a full compilable test app which demonstrates the issue. I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

The project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.13.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The "Program.cs" file:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Benchmark;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<UnderTest>();
    }
}

[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
public class UnderTest
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingBitConverter()
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        writeUsingBitConverter(stream, _array);
    }

    static void writeUsingBitConverter(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        foreach (var sample in array)
        {
            output.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sample), 0, sizeof(double));
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingMarshal()
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        writeUsingMarshal(stream, _array);
    }

    static void writeUsingMarshal(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        const int SIZE_BYTES = sizeof(double);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE_BYTES];
        IntPtr ptr    = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SIZE_BYTES);

        foreach (var sample in array)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sample, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, SIZE_BYTES);
            output.Write(buffer, 0, SIZE_BYTES);
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }

    #if NET6_0_OR_GREATER

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingSpan()
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        writeUsingSpan(stream, _array);
    }

    static void writeUsingSpan(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        var span  = array.AsSpan();
        var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(span);

        output.Write(bytes);
    }

    #endif // NET6_0_OR_GREATER

    readonly double[] _array = new double[10_000];
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in BenchmarkDotNet. I would recommend creating an issue in project's github.

Comment: You probably need to put the `#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER` around the `[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]` attribute too.

Comment: @DavidG I'll try that in a bit and report back.

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately that doesn't help - the result is the same.

Comment: OK, next option... make two different classes, one with `RuntimeMoniker.Net60` and one with `RuntimeMoniker.Net48`, then use `BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly, DefaultConfig.Instance.WithOptions(ConfigOptions.JoinSummary).WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableLogFile));`?

Comment: @DavidG That workaround works - if you post it as an answer I can accept it and append a working compilable console app to show what I ended up with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From memory, Benchmark.NET will run benchmarks for all frameworks with some internal wizardry. So instead of using the existing [preprocessor symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754123/conditional-per-targetframework-in-msbuild-15/42754213#42754213) it's probably better to split your tests across two classes with different `RuntimeMoniker` attributes. For example:

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
public class UnderTestNet48
{
    // Benchmarks
}

[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
public class UnderTestNet60
{
    // Benchmarks
}
```

And now you need to modify the code that runs the benchmarks since the they are split across classes, something like this will work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var config = DefaultConfig.Instance.
        .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.JoinSummary)
        .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableLogFile);

    BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly, config);
}
```

---

[EDIT from OP (Matthew Watson)]

I managed to implement this thanks to this answer.

I managed to reduce the code duplication a bit by putting the common test methods into a protected base class, then providing two derived classes - one for the `net48` benchmark and one for the `net5.0` benchmark.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Configs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Benchmark;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run(
            typeof(Program).Assembly, 
            DefaultConfig.Instance
               .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.JoinSummary)
               .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableLogFile));
    }
}

public abstract class UnderTestBase
{
    protected static Stream CreateStream()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(); // Or Stream.Null
    }

    protected void WriteUsingBitConverter(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        foreach (var sample in array)
        {
            output.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sample), 0, sizeof(double));
        }
    }

    protected void WriteUsingMarshal(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        const int SIZE_BYTES = sizeof(double);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE_BYTES];
        IntPtr ptr    = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SIZE_BYTES);

        foreach (var sample in array)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sample, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, SIZE_BYTES);
            output.Write(buffer, 0, SIZE_BYTES);
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }

    #if NET6_0_OR_GREATER
    
    protected void WriteUsingSpan(Stream output, double[] array)
    {
        var span  = array.AsSpan();
        var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(span);

        output.Write(bytes);
    }

    #endif // NET6_0_OR_GREATER

    protected readonly double[] Array = new double[100_000];
}

[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
public class UnderTestNet48: UnderTestBase
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingBitConverter()
    {
        using var stream = CreateStream();
        WriteUsingBitConverter(stream, Array);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingMarshal()
    {
        using var stream = CreateStream();
        WriteUsingMarshal(stream, Array);
    }
}

[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
public class UnderTestNet60: UnderTestBase
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingBitConverter()
    {
        using var stream = CreateStream();
        WriteUsingBitConverter(stream, Array);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingMarshal()
    {
        using var stream = CreateStream();
        WriteUsingMarshal(stream, Array);
    }

    #if NET6_0_OR_GREATER

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingSpan()
    {
        using var stream = CreateStream();
        WriteUsingSpan(stream, Array);
    }

    #endif // NET6_0_OR_GREATER
}
```

Which results in this output:

```
|           Type |            Method |                Job |            Runtime |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|--------------- |------------------ |------------------- |------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
| UnderTestNet60 | UsingBitConverter |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 4,110.8 us |  81.53 us | 151.13 us |
| UnderTestNet60 |      UsingMarshal |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 | 5,774.0 us | 114.78 us | 194.90 us |
| UnderTestNet60 |         UsingSpan |           .NET 6.0 |           .NET 6.0 |   521.6 us |   5.13 us |   4.80 us |
| UnderTestNet48 | UsingBitConverter | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 | 2,987.2 us |  35.60 us |  29.73 us |
| UnderTestNet48 |      UsingMarshal | .NET Framework 4.8 | .NET Framework 4.8 | 5,616.9 us |  57.85 us |  48.30 us |
```

(As an aside, one interesting result is that the `UsingBitConverter()` method actually seems to run faster with `net48` compared to `net6.0` - although this is dwarfed by the massive improvement in speed offered by `Span<T>`.)

[/EDIT from OP (Matthew Watson)]

Answer (score 2):

It has been discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/1226#issuecomment-532144829:

When running the host process targetting XYZ framework, BDN is using the reflection to obtain the list of available methods (benchmarks). If you are using `#if` defines, then the list of benchmarks is going to be different per host process target framework.

Performance repo docs describe how to compare multiple runtimes performance here:
https://github.com/dotnet/performance/blob/master/docs/benchmarkdotnet.md#multiple-runtimes

> The host process needs to be the lowest common API denominator of the runtimes you want to compare!

You can read more about benchmarking multiple tfms in https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/toolchains.html#multiple-frameworks-support