# How can I benchmark two methods each running on different framework?

Tags: c#, benchmarkdotnet

I neet to compare two implementations of the same functionality but done for two frameworks: .net 4.6.2 and .net 7

How do I define this benchmark?

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but I think you should run two separate benchmarks...

Comment: @Marco yes, feels like that.  I'm curious how I would match methods if there were many for each benchmark.

Comment: Well, each benchmark can report a lot of _"functions"_ to be checked... if you call these functions the same way between the two benchmarks, I'd say it will be easy to match them. I beg your pardon, I'm just guessing...

Comment: don't quite understand your question, isn't that basically the default behaviour - you have two methods with the implementations you want to test - and just declare the attributes for the frameworks as needed eg. `[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net472)] [SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp30)]`  ?!? - so basically the very first example on https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet - two methods and 4 frameworks

Comment: @RandRandom, well, while this would work, it will yeild 4 result 2 of which are irrelevant. I want each benchmark method run against one target framework.

Comment: okay, than simply declare two classes, each with the desired attribute eg. as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274948

Answer (score 3):

I have created 2 library projects, one in .net 4.6.2 and one in .net 7 with the same class and function.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int CalcInt32(int OperationsPerInvoke)
        {
            int firstDigit = 135;
            int secondDigit = 145;

            for (int i = 0; i < OperationsPerInvoke; i++)
            {
                firstDigit += secondDigit;
            }
            return firstDigit;
        }
    }
}
```

After that I've created a new test project .net 7 that will do the tests by invoking the method from each assembly:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System.Reflection;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<PerformanceTest>();
public class PerformanceTest
{
    const int OperationsPerInvoke = 4096;

    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public int TestClassLibrary7()
    {
        var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("d:\\Teste\\.NetGeneral\\_Dlls\\ClassLibrary1\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\ClassLibrary1.dll");
        var myType = myAssembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1");
        if (myType == null)
            return 0;
        MethodInfo dllGetMethod = myType.GetMethod("CalcInt32", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        object res = dllGetMethod?.Invoke(null, new object[] { OperationsPerInvoke });
        return (int)res;
    }


    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public int TestClassLibrary462()
    {
        var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("d:\\Teste\\.NetGeneral\\_Dlls\\ClassLibrary2\\bin\\Debug\\ClassLibrary2.dll");
        var myType = myAssembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1");
        if (myType == null)
            return 0;
        MethodInfo dllGetMethod = myType.GetMethod("CalcInt32", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        object res = dllGetMethod?.Invoke(null, new object[] { OperationsPerInvoke });
        return (int)res;
    }
}
```

and it's working. Here are some results for my test:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TestClassLibrary7 | 0.1374 ns | 0.0017 ns | 0.0015 ns |
| TestClassLibrary462 | 0.1308 ns | 0.0019 ns | 0.0017 ns |

Comment: I am surprised you could load .net 462 assembly from .net 7

Comment: This compiles and works, nothing to say. But honestly If I have to create two libraries and call them from another project, then why not using Benchmark within the two projects already existing (one for each framework)? I understand that in this way you have a single result easily comparable, but I'm not sure the result is correct. You're executing the code within both libraries in a different framework and in a different context, so I won't bet on such benchmarks. Naturally this is just my opinion and I perfectly know I could be wrong...